# Rails 7 nested form AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to create a nested form with Rails 7 and am running into a few issues, here's my approach so far:

Models:

```
#models/customer
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
#models/address

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer

  validates :line_1, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :province, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true
  validates :postcode, presence: true
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for :customer, :class => 'row g-3' do |form| %>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <%= form.label :name %>
   <%= form.text_field :name, required: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= form.label :contact_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :contact_name, required: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= form.label :email_address %>
    <%= form.email_field :email_address, required: true, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= form.label :phone_number %>
    <%= form.text_field :phone_number, required: false, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
   <%= form.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= form.label :line_1 %>
      <%= a.text_field :line_1, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= form.label :line_2 %>
      <%= a.text_field :line_2, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= form.label :city %>
      <%= a.text_field :city, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= form.label :province %>
      <%= a.text_field :province, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= form.label :postcode %>
      <%= a.text_field :postcode, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= form.label :country %>
      <%= a.text_field :country, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "Create", :class => 'w-50 btn btn-lg btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    customer = Customer.new(create_customer_params)
    if customer.save
      redirect_to dashboard_customers_path, notice: 'Customer created'
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def create_customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :contact_name, :email_address, :phone_number,
                                     address: %i[line_1 line_2 city province postcode country])
  end
end
```

So upon submitting the form, I get the following error:

```
Address(#188880) expected, got {"line_1"=>"3333", "line_2"=>"", "city"=>"Sydney", "province"=>"NS", "postcode"=>"abc1234", "country"=>"Canada"} which is an instance of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#166940)
```

I've searched around and came across this blog post which is similar to what I'm trying to do: https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/learning/rails/nested-forms.html and my model and relations look correct.

I considered that maybe it was expecting a symbol for `:address` opposed to a hash, so I changed the controller to use:

```
    params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :contact_name, :email_address, :phone_number,
                                     address_attributes: %i[line_1 line_2 city province postcode country])
```

Which resulted in the following error: `Unpermitted parameter: :address`, so I updated the front end to use: `<%= form.fields_for :address_attributes do |a| %>`

and am now getting:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in CustomersController#create
unknown attribute 'customer_id' for Address.
```

Comment: You are not showing all your code, it's impossible to help with so little information. Please start by posting your full controller code, also post your stack trace please so we can see which params are actually being passed in

Comment: Your form and models look to be OK, so the issue will most likely be within your controller

Comment: on view the form helper method `form.fields_for :address` will create `address_attributes` params, so on controller you have to `..permit(.., address_attributes: ...)`,. Check call request on your console for sure.